# how can I use selected menu item value inside userdefined method in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am working on android application. I want to bind data in listview as per the value selected in Menu Item. But I can't used that selected menu item value inside my user defined method getdatalatlog(double latitude, double longitude).

Below is my code.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_serch:
        openSearch();
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.five:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected 5km",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    case R.id.ten:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected 10km",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     break;
    case R.id.fifteen:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected 15km",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
return true;
```

Below is my Userdefined method:

```
  private void getdatalatlog(double latitude, double longitude) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String url = "http://192.168.0.106/PHP/webservice/comments.php?latitude='"+latitude+"'&longitude='"+longitude+"'";
    aq.progress(R.id.progressBar1).ajax(url, JSONObject.class, this,"jsonCallback");

}`
```

In menuitem the vaue is 5, 10, 15. I want to use that selected value inside my above userdefind method.
Please guide me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to pass the value to your method?

Comment: What exactly your issue is ?

Comment: yaa i want to pass selected menu item value in my userdefined method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a variable called `value` at the top of your class and initialize it with some default value inside your onCreate() method.

Then, when the user clicks on the menu item, set your desired value(5, 10 or 15) to the `value` variable. For example, inside your `switch` statement

```
case R.id.five:
    value = 5;
    break;

case R.id.ten:
    value = 10;
    break;
....
```

Then, you can use the `value` variable inside of your method.

Comment: i try to do as you suggest but after I select incase 10 then how can i call my userdefined method again??

Comment: Do you want to call it after you select the menu item?

Comment: initially when activity start the data is bind as distance 5 km and then when user select 10 or 15 or again 5 km the data is bind as per that.

Comment: Can't you call the method from inside your switch-case statement?

Comment: no i cant because its use parameter latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the selected menu as parameter to getdatalatlog like below when selected
getdatalatlog(double latitude, double longitude, int R.id.five)

```
case R.id.five:
    getdatalatlog(double latitude, double longitude, int R.id.five);
    break;
```

or

Declare the global variable selectedMenu and assign the value (eg. R.id.five) to this variable when selected and use that in your method.

```
case R.id.five:
        selectedMenu = R.id.five;
        break;
```

Then you can check the value like if(selectedMenu == R.id.five)

Comment: i cant use my method inside switch case.

Comment: What if you assigned the value to selectedMenu and get it in method getdatalatlog.